# Laravel 4 query display

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having a tiny problem. I can't find a way to return queries (to display on an php page).
I'm using something like this:

```
    public function players()
{
   $players = Player::all();
   return View::make('aac.test', array('players' => $players));
}
```

My test php page is blank. On the profiler it shows that the query was executed.

I've also tried without something like this:

```
    public function test()
{
         $id = 3;
         $player = Player::find($id);
         $name = $player->name;
         $level = $player->level;

         return View::make('aac.test');

}
```

and then in the layout:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <? $name ?>``
</body>
</html>
```

or even echoing that. It just won't display. The query is executed. I'm kind of new to all of this, if you could explain me..

It only works if I do it like this:

```
        public function test()
{
         $id = 3;
         $player = Player::find($id);
         $name = $player->name;
         $level = $player->level;

         return $name;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps see if it solves your problem.

- First make sure that the view exists in `app/views/aac/test.php`.
- Check if your route is deifined correctly e.g `Route::get('/players','ControllerName@players')`.

Then if you want to return all players in your controller pass the players to the view

```
public function players()
{
 $players = Player::all();
 return View::make('aac.test')->with('players' => $players);
}
```

And in your view `views/aac/test.php` you need to iterate through players. (e.g you can display them in a list)

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($players as $player):?>
    <li><?php echo $player->name; ?></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

If you want just one player

```
 public function oneplayer()
 {
  $player = Player::find(1);
  return View::make('aac.test')->with('player',$player); 
 }
```

And in your view now you have access to the player object

```
 <?php echo $player->name; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I wanted to ask you one more question. I have two tables 'accounts' and 'players'. Both are creation-type like if you know what I mean. In the 'players' column there is an 'account_id' which matches 'id' in 'accounts' table. How could I display, let's say, when a person logs in ('accounts' table), display the matching players from 'players' table, with the matching account_id? I don't want it to work with one account, I want it to work with all accounts.

Comment: Please if the answer solved your problem mark it as accepted. For the other question first you have to relate the models and then it's very simple to query for the relations. You can read about relationships in the docs  http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Comment: I've already done the relations. I've tried pretty much things, but couldn't really do it. If you could give me some kind of an example code, I would be grateful.

Comment: Sorry but it's a little hard to understand what you are trying to do from the comments. It would be better if you post it as another question with code you've already written and explain better what you want to achieve.